# Jsoup connect error 403 and 503

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, cloudflare

I've been using jsoup connect method for getting DOM of certain websites for some time (made my personal bot and I make 20-30 request per day to those websites). Namely I can open and browse that website but my java program can't access it since today, one thing I noticed changed is that CloudFlare is checking my browser (prevention of DDoS attacks) . My connect code looks like this

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .timeout(0)
                .get();
```

and now I get error 503. I tried changing userAgent to only "Mozzila/5.0" and than I get error 403. Doesn't make any sense to my, but my suspicion is on the Cloudflare system.

Edit:

I discovered that CloudFlare protection "I'am under attack" requires for browser to have JavaScript and Cookies on and grants access to website after 5 seconds. How can I recreate that situation with my Java program?

Comment: When you use a bot, the site indicates no bot, and/or execute a high load, providers block you. Usually this is limited for a day or so. Adjust your bot to be more friendly (and use a much newer user agent)

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some reference on how to get my bot more friendly?

Comment: The main part is in the distribution of your requests: Put a decent delay (30s for example) between requesting different pages so that your bot behaves more "human like"

Comment: Could it be that Cloudflare has a advanced algorithm for detection of bots?

Answer (score 1):

Every website has its limitation to avoid crash or attack. It happens to me when I want to access github data. I did not see any authentication in your code (you may hide it, which I can understand). Sometimes they will give you higher access limitation with higher frequency. So try give authentication is good.

Another problem is that you set timeout to 0. 
        **ConnectionTimeout=0**
is bad, make it something reasonable like 30 seconds.

Comment: agreed,because sometimes(don't know why) timeout gives the actual problem but it decieves( don't know why) you and gives another problem.